# Mysql stored proc to select particular columns data of a table into temporary table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have a table test which has the following columns

*`test1, test2, test3, abc_xxx, abc_yyy, abc_zzz, abc_ppp, abc_yyy, test4, test5`*

get all the column names starting with pattern "abc_"

after that select distinct data of all these columns starting with "abc_" into a single column of some temporary table
temp table is fileds

```
colnames = get the column names starting with pattern "abc_" 
for each colname

select distinct(colname) into temp
```

Finally temp should have distinct data of all the columns starting with pattern "abc_" of test table

i tried with the following stored proc,

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test1;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test1()


BEGIN

    DECLARE cols varchar(255);
    DECLARE MY_CURSOR  CURSOR FOR SELECT columns from fields;


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fields;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp( id BIGINT(20) );
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fields( columns varchar(255) );

    INSERT INTO fields select Column_name from Information_schema.columns where Table_name like 'test' and Column_name like '%abc%';

    OPEN MY_CURSOR;

     traverse_ids: LOOP

    FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO cols;

            IF cols IS NULL
            THEN
                LEAVE traverse_metrics;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO temp SELECT distinct(cols) FROM test;
            END IF;


     END LOOP traverse_ids;

     CLOSE MY_CURSOR;


   END //

 DELIMITER ;
```

but its returning me the error "No data – zero rows fetched, selected or processed"

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE updateDone INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET updateDone = 1;

added these two lines which prevented the error

but the issue is when i call the procedure, it is in executing state for a long time,dont know whats wrong with the proc. can someone figure it out or provide an alternative

Answer (score 0):

modifying the IF logic fixed the problem
FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO col;

```
 IF done

  THEN
  LEAVE doUpdate;
  ELSE
```